# Google Sheets Array Error using Or asterisk

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I have the below array which is checking multiple cells for conditions. However I am receiving an error when column H has a value in it and the value contains letters.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A:A="","", if(row(A:A)=1,"Cert Generated?",
if(H:H="","N/A",
if((AF:AF=""*+H:H<>""),"No","Yes")))))
```

I receive the error "Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'P02269895' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.".

However, I am not adding/multiplying. From what I know, AND/OR statements need to use a +/* in an array.

What am I missing?

TYIA

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*replace this part of the formula*

```js
(AF:AF=""*H:H<>"")
```

*with*

```js
(AF:AF="")*(H:H<>"")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was driving me nuts.